# La alerta no se muestra

Tags: javascript

Hola como va? Debo calcular el indice imc que es el peso divido la altura al cuadrado.  Estoy teniendo un problema en el cual las alertas en ciertos casos (como en altura 1.80 y peso 60) no se muestra. Quisiera saber si alguien sabe como solucionarlo. Saludos. Creo que esto se debe a que es un numero periodico el resultado del calculo del IMC pero me encantaria saber si alguien sabe como solucionarlo.

(EDIT)

Probe lo que me dijo la respuesta de abajo y me figura la alerta (arreglado). A continuación el codigo:

```js
var dni; var nombre; var edad;  var peso;  var altura; var imc;

dni = parseInt (prompt("Ingrese el DNI.")); //DNI determinado
nombre = (prompt("Ingrese el nombre.")); //nombre determinado
edad = parseInt (prompt("Ingrese la edad.")); //edad determinada
peso = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese el peso en kilogramos (kg)")); //peso sin calcular
altura = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese la altura en metros")); //altura sin calcular

altura = altura * altura;

imc = peso / altura;


switch (true) {
    case (imc <= 18.5):
        alert("bajo peso");
        break;
    case (24.9 > imc && imc > 18.5):
        alert("normopeso");
        break;
    case (26.9 > imc && imc > 25):
        alert("sobrepeso grado I");
        break;
    case (29.9 > imc && imc > 27):
        alert("sobrepeso grado II");
        break;
    case (34.9 > imc && imc > 30):
        alert("obesidad de tipo I");
        break;
    case (39.9 > imc && imc > 35):
        alert("obesidad de tipo II");
        break;
    case (49.9 > imc && imc > 40):
        alert("obesidad de tipo III (morbida)");
        break;
    case (imc >= 50):
        alert("obesidad de tipo IV (extrema)");
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
}

document.write("El DNI es " + dni + ("<br>"));
document.write("El nombre es " + nombre + ("<br>"));
document.write("La edad es " + edad + ("<br>"));
document.write("El IMC es " + imc.toFixed(3) + ("<br>"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio Tipo Examen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola. Lo que ocurre es que el resultado de 180cm con 60kg da exactamente 18.5 de IMC. Ninguno de tus casos en el switch contempla ese valor porque tienes rangos que no incluyen tus valores exactos, para que los incluyan debes usar los operadores >= o <=. Es decir, si quieres incluir a 18.5 en su respectivo caso, harías algo como esto: 24.9 > imc >= 18.5

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenido a Stack Overflow y te doy como consejo no mencionar para qué haces el código si no es necesario. Por ejemplo, decir que es para el colegio puede hacer que otros usuarios piensen que quieres que te hagan la tarea. Pero obviamente no es tu caso porque tienes todo hecho y solo intentas encontrar el error que no permite el buen funcionamiento de tu programa.

Comment: Gracias @V0LT3RR4 de todas maneras me sigue sin salir el alert. Donde inserto el codigo para mostrarte?

Comment: Lo inserte en la pregunta original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus condicionales estan mal escritas, te dejo un ejemplo con la forma correcta de comparar intervalos.

```js
var dni; var nombre; var edad;  var peso;  var altura; var imc;

dni = parseInt (prompt("Ingrese el DNI.")); //DNI determinado
nombre = (prompt("Ingrese el nombre.")); //nombre determinado
edad = parseInt (prompt("Ingrese la edad.")); //edad determinada
peso = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese el peso en kilogramos (kg)")); //peso sin calcular
altura = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese la altura en metros")); //altura sin calcular

altura = altura*altura;

imc = peso / altura;

switch (true) {
    case (imc < 18.5):
        alert("bajo peso");
        break;
    case (24.9 > imc && imc > 18.5):
        alert("normopeso");
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
}

document.write("El DNI es " + dni + ("<br>"));
document.write("El nombre es " + nombre + ("<br>"));
document.write("La edad es " + edad + ("<br>"));
document.write("El IMC es " + imc.toFixed(1) + ("<br>"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio Tipo Examen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm me sigue sin dar la alerta. Como pongo el codigo para que lo veas? Aca no me entra.

Comment: Lo inserte en la pregunta original.

Comment: En la pregunta original tu codigo funciona correctamente

Comment: Entonces debes tener otro error, revisa la consola

Comment: Cierto. Fue un error mio. Estaba viendo una version vieja de mi trabajo disculpas y muchas gracias. Ahi marco tu respuesta como la correcta. Saludos! @alanfcm

Answer (score 0):

Las condiciones no consideran cuando el imc es igual a 18.5. Para cambiar esto tendrás que incluir el 18.5 en alguno de los rangos por medio de un >= o un <=.

Esto también se tendrá que cambiar para los demás rangos, no solo para el 18.5. Abajo te dejo el código funcionando también para 25, 27, 30, 35, 40 y 50 de imc.

```js
var dni; var nombre; var edad;  var peso;  var altura; var imc;

dni = parseInt (prompt("Ingrese el DNI.")); //DNI determinado
nombre = (prompt("Ingrese el nombre.")); //nombre determinado
edad = parseInt (prompt("Ingrese la edad.")); //edad determinada
peso = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese el peso en kilogramos (kg)")); //peso sin calcular
altura = parseFloat(prompt("Ingrese la altura en metros")); //altura sin calcular

altura = altura * altura;

imc = peso / altura;


switch (true) {
    case (imc <= 18.5):
        alert("bajo peso");
        break;
    case (25 >= imc && imc > 18.5):
        alert("normopeso");
        break;
    case (27 >= imc && imc > 25):
        alert("sobrepeso grado I");
        break;
    case (30 >= imc && imc > 27):
        alert("sobrepeso grado II");
        break;
    case (35 >= imc && imc > 30):
        alert("obesidad de tipo I");
        break;
    case (40 >= imc && imc > 35):
        alert("obesidad de tipo II");
        break;
    case (50 >= imc && imc > 40):
        alert("obesidad de tipo III (morbida)");
        break;
    case (imc > 50):
        alert("obesidad de tipo IV (extrema)");
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
}

document.write("El DNI es " + dni + ("<br>"));
document.write("El nombre es " + nombre + ("<br>"));
document.write("La edad es " + edad + ("<br>"));
document.write("El IMC es " + imc.toFixed(3) + ("<br>"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio Tipo Examen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```